# Different types of users of a group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I am looking for a better way to implement following situation...

A `group` has_many `users`. When creating group I want to add different types users at same time.
If user  type selected (from dropdown) is 'Salesperson' then I have to fill his/her earnings (year, earning).
If user type selected is 'Supervisor' then I just have to fill his/her email.
If user type is 'Bot' then nothing needs to be filled.

Right-now I am just showing respective fields and storing hidden (other types' data) simply null using nested forms.
I am sure there's a better way, I just need a lead.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to store the different types of users in different tables (salespeople, supervisors and bots) so that you don't need to pass the additional attributes as all.

If you are using a single table, then you can also set default values for attributes to nil so that you don't need to explicitly pass nil to the attributes when you don't want to set them:

```
add_column :users, :salary, :float, :default => nil
```

NOTE: In MySQL the default will be NULL, so you don't need to explicitly specify this in your migrations.